# Firebase hosting is having some issues

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

The react app is working fine on localhost. But hosted site is facing some problem as shown in the below mentioned image. Initially it was working fine but after few days it started showing this issue. All of my firebase app is facing the same problem.[chrome_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gra3.png)
[firebase_hosting_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ1sc.png)

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

If you're in APAC or EMEA, you may be affected by this [outage on the Firebase status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/xukDZcayBqgTGBy9Le3S):

> Firebase Hosting is aware of some reports of connection issues in the APAC and EMEA regions. We are currently investigating.

If that sounds what you're seeing, I'd recommend following that page for updates.